# Consuming REST Web Service and Parsing XML data in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, xml-parsing

I need to consume a REST web service from my android device. 
I have to give the following inputs.

1)Latitude & Longitude of current position

2)Time Zone

the url looks like this

```
www.example.com/someservice/mylatitude/mylongitude/mylocation
```

it returns the xml response something like this.

```
<SomeInformations>
  <ItemList>
    <Item>
      <Current>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <EndTime>String content</EndTime>
        <Phase>String content</Phase>
      </Current>
      <Next>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <StartTime>String content</StartTime>
        <Phase>String content</Phase>
      </Next>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Current>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <EndTime>String content</EndTime>
        <Phase>String content</Phase>
      </Current>
      <Next>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <StartTime>String content</StartTime>
        <Phase>String content</Phase>
      </Next>
    </Item>
  </ItemList>
  <InfoList>
    <Info>
      <Current>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <EndTime>String content</EndTime>
      </Current>
      <Next>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <StartTime>String content</StartTime>
      </Next>
    </Info>
    <Info>
      <Current>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <EndTime>String content</EndTime>
      </Current>
      <Next>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <StartTime>String content</StartTime>
      </Next>
    </Info>
  </InfoList>
  <GameList>
    <Game>
      <Current>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <EndTime>String content</EndTime>
      </Current>
      <Next>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <StartTime>String content</StartTime>
      </Next>
    </Game>
    <Game>
      <Current>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <EndTime>String content</EndTime>
      </Current>
      <Next>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <StartTime>String content</StartTime>
      </Next>
    </Game>
  </GameList>
  <GameallList>
    <Game>
      <Current>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <EndTime>String content</EndTime>
      </Current>
      <Next>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <StartTime>String content</StartTime>
      </Next>
    </Game>
    <Game>
      <Current>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <EndTime>String content</EndTime>
      </Current>
      <Next>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <StartTime>String content</StartTime>
      </Next>
    </Game>
  </GameallList>
  <Specialitems>
    <Time1>String content</Time1>
    <Time2>String content</Time2>
    <Time3>String content</Time3>
    <Time4>String content</Time4>
    <Time5>String content</Time5>
  </Specialitems>

  <ImptList>
    <impt>
      <Current>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <EndTime>String content</EndTime>
      </Current>
      <Next>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <StartTime>String content</StartTime>
      </Next>
    </impt>
    <impt>
      <Current>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <EndTime>String content</EndTime>
      </Current>
      <Next>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <StartTime>String content</StartTime>
      </Next>
    </impt>
  </imptList>
  <PeriodList>
    <Period>
      <Current>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <EndTime>String content</EndTime>
      </Current>
      <Next>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <StartTime>String content</StartTime>
      </Next>
    </Period>
    <Period>
      <Current>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <EndTime>String content</EndTime>
      </Current>
      <Next>
        <Name>String content</Name>
        <StartTime>String content</StartTime>
      </Next>
    </Period>
  </PeriodList>
  <PostitonList>
    <Position>
      <Main>
        <sub1>String content</sub1>
        <sub2>String content</sub2>
      </Main>
      <dummy1>String content</dummy1>
      <dummy2>String content</dummy2>
      <dummy3>String content</dummy3>
      <dummy4>String content</dummy4>
      <dummy5>true</dummy5>
      <dummy6>String content</dummy6>
    </Position>
    <Position>
      <Main>
        <sub1>String content</sub1>
        <sub2>String content</sub2>
      </Main>
      <dummy1>String content</dummy1>
      <dummy2>String content</dummy2>
      <dummy3>String content</dummy3>
      <dummy4>String content</dummy4>
      <dummy5>true</dummy5>
      <dummy6>String content</dummy6>
    </Position>
  </PostitonList>
</SomeInformations>
```

How can i do the above. I am beginner in Android.Suggest A simple way.
Need Quicker Response. Thnks for spending your time here.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this XML format ? I mean are you trying to display it in a ListView or any?

Comment: Not in list view.have to store those thing based on their categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly have you tried, and what are the issues you've run across? This is a pretty standard scenario, so you should try it yourself before you come here and ask people to do your work for you.

If it was me I would start here: [Android XML Pull Parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) which can read in your XML file and let you get data back out.

And you can look here for how to make the HTTP call so read the XML file: [Android HTTP Client](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)

Comment: yeah. I started to look into Android XML Pull Parser & Android HTTP Client. I ll come back with my issues!