# Parse 2 Levels of XML android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser, android-xmlpullparser

Please correct the table if it is wrong, ,I'm not entirely sure what to title this.

I am trying to parse my XML in android and i have code that should work, but the problem is there are multiple levels of tags i need to get into.

Here is an example of my XML:

```
<dsxout>
    <uselessTag>unnecasary info</uselessTag>
    <results>
         <listing>
             <title>I'm a Title</title>
             <description>very amusing description</description>
         </listing>
         <listing>
         ...
         </listing>
    </results>
</dsxout>
```

Here is where my parsing gets stuck:

```
private List readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    List entries = new ArrayList();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "readFeed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "dsxout");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
```

**The line below just spits out the tag uselessTag and results**

```
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Starts by looking for the entry tag
        if (name.equals("listing")) {
            entries.add(readEntry(parser));
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return entries;
}
```

The problem is it only reads to the second level of tags and not inside the results tag so it cannot find listing.

How do I go another level in while reading?

Comment: when consuming from `webservices` it's a good practice to use some libraries like [ksoap2](http://karanbalkar.com/2014/03/tutorial-78-using-ksoap2-in-android/), it will save you some time and they are less error prone then hardcoding. You can refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139084/consuming-rest-web-service-and-parsing-xml-data-in-android) for further detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this statement seems to have fixed the problem

```
 if (name.equals("results")) {
   String nextTokedn = "Next Level " + parser.nextTag();
 }
```